# Understanding Closures For Decorators

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a decorator that takes a few arguments, and can decorate arbitrary functions. After reading a few code examples, and stepping through the debugger I've figured out *how* to write it. But I don't fully understand *why* it works.

```
def bar(arg1):

    def inner_bar(f):

        def inner_inner_bar(*args, **kwargs):
            new_args = (x + arg1 for x in args)

            return f(*new_args, **kwargs)

        return inner_inner_bar

    return inner_bar


@bar(4)
def foo(x, y):
    print("Sum is {0}".format(x+y))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo(1, 2)


Sum is 11
```

What I don't fully grasp is how/why the function `f` exists in the scope of `inner_bar` but not `bar`. And similarly that `args` and `kwargs` exist in the scope of `inner_inner_bar` but not `inner_bar`.

What is Python doing when I use `@bar` that makes the different variables available in the different methods of my decorator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is Python doing when I use @bar that makes the different variables available in the different methods of my decorator?

Note that you're not just using `@bar`, you're using `@bar(4)`.  It works like this:

- `bar(4)` returns a function (`inner_bar`)
- Using `@bar(4)` to decorate `foo` calls `inner_bar(foo)`.
- `inner_bar(foo)` returns a function (`inner_inner_bar`)
- This function (`inner_inner_bar`) is assigned back to the name `foo`
- When you call `foo`, you are calling `inner_inner_bar`, so whatever arguments you pass are passed as the `*args` and `**kwargs`

What Python is "doing" is calling the functions involved.  All of the variables you're asking about (`f`, `args` and `kwargs`) are just function arguments, which, as usual, become available when their function is called.  `f` becomes available when `inner_bar` is called, namely when you apply the decorator.  `*args` and `**kwargs` become available when `inner_inner_bar` is called, namely when you call the decorated function.  The only thing that is available when you write `bar(4)` is `arg1`, because the other functions haven't been called yet.

Comment: Cheers. I feel like I've got my head wrapped around it now.